# Best practice to post in spring data rest

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, hateoas

I would like to know what is the best practice to do the post in this class.

```java
@Component
public class IngredientToNutrionalValueIdConverter implements BackendIdConverter {
    @Override
    public Serializable fromRequestId(String s, Class<?> aClass) {

        if (s != null) {

        NutrionalValueIngredientId ptid = new NutrionalValueIngredientId();

        String[] idParts = s.split("-");

        ptid.setIngredientid(Long.valueOf(idParts[0]));
        ptid.setNutrionalvalueid(Long.valueOf(idParts[1]));
        return ptid;
    }
        return BackendIdConverter.DefaultIdConverter.INSTANCE.fromRequestId(s, aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public String toRequestId(Serializable s, Class<?> aClass) {
        NutrionalValueIngredientId ptid = (NutrionalValueIngredientId) s;
            return String.format("%s-%s", ptid.getIngredientid(), ptid.getNutrionalvalueid());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return JoinedNutrionalValueIngredient.class.equals(aClass);
    }

}
```

JSON

```json
{
    "id":{
        "ingredientid": "ingredients/1",
        "nutrionalvalueid": "nutrionalValues/1"
    },
    "matrixUnit": "50 g a porzione",
    "value": 4,
    "valueType": "ponderata"
}
```

What is the best practice to pass the "id" in the JSON? Directly with the id or with the url?
If I have to proceed with the url, how can I extract the id from it?

Comment: Generally, I think you will find that most JSON payloads will contain identifiers as regular data elements. If you want to provide 'resource identifiers' as well, the best way to do that is to use HATEOAS links. Spring provides a straightforward way to include [HATEOAS links](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-hateoas-tutorial).

Comment: As a dependency I used spring-data-rest, so I do not need to generate ResourceSupport, Link, etc.
The problem is that I need to extract the id from the link. @Tom Drake

Comment: If you're web-service endpoint is being called, then the identifier should be defined as a Path Parameter.

If you're simply trying to parse URLs to obtain id's from json that you generated somewhere else, then I think you're making your life too difficult. I'd add these id's as unadorned data elements to your json payloads, and then just use them in the places that you need to use them. Parsing urls makes your application brittle, in that if those urls change, so will your parsing logic.

Comment: Since the url make my application brittle, I will pass the id.
But at other points in the program I use the uri. Also in this case I have to pass the id or can I leave the uri directly?
{
 "name": "vitamine",
 "unit": "kg",
 "source": "computed value",
 "category": 
 "nutrionalValueCategories/1"
}@TomDrake

Comment: You can and probably should do both. URL links are provided for clients that want to use the url without having to know how to construct urls to your various rest endpoints. But the identifiers stored in fields in your json payloads can be used directly in your services for whatever purposes they are intended for.